# Android Texting App That Works Like iMessages

Tags: android, iphone-app

I like how iMessages on Apple works because it has additional features if the user is using iMessages but it sends it over text messages instead as a backup inside the same application.  It simple displays the user as [blue if you are using iMessages or green otherwise](http://cdn.solveyourtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/difference-text-message-imessage-1.jpg).

Is there an equivalent of this for Android?

Besides gracefully degrading these are features I like in iMessages that I would like in the messaging app for Android.

- A way to send decent quality pictures & videos
- Ideally a way to view messages on laptop like iMessages(I believe this only works for iMessages & not SMS messages for fairly obvious reasons)
- [displays when the other user has read the message](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/02_read_time_at_end.png)
- [displays when the user is typing](http://static1.businessinsider.com/image/56996788dd0895a06c8b460e/those-dots-you-see-in-imessage-are-more-complicated-than-you-think.jpg)

Apps I have tried(and at least at this point haven't figured out how to work like this is): WhatsApp, FB Messenger, WeChat, G Hangouts, Telegram, & G Voice

Hangouts & G Voice is quite close but you have to have 2 numbers to get this to work and you are calling through Google's servers(I think) which in my experience makes it very intermittent with calls.

Comment: I'd suggest Telegram. All your 4 Key points works well in TG.It has more security than other apps which you already tried. It has a dedicated standalone application for PC. _displays when the other user has read the message_ > `double tick` under sent message denotes user has read it. _displays when the user is typing_ > it shows on the top side of the chat window( below user name). TG voice calls are E2E encrypted.

Comment: @w͏̢in̡͢g͘̕ed̨p̢͟a͞n͏͏t̡͜͝he̸r̴ The CEO of Telegram has a track record of bad security decisions: https://thehackernews.com/2016/06/vk-com-data-breach.html